# How to use kismet as a command-line tool

Tags: networking, wifi

I tried [kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/), but it keeps putting me into this insane ncurses UI mode.  In this mode, everything is a keyboard shortcut and it is not documented on the screen.  Then when I exit, my WiFi stops working and I need to reboot.  I just want something like tcpdump so I can sed, awk, and less my way to what I want to read.

Does anyone know how I can get kismet to chill out or at least give my wifi card back when I'm done with it?  Is there another tool that would fit my needs better?

Comment: How is this related to programming? You probably want superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. This fixes it on my Ubuntu system: after using Kismet, I disable wifi by unchecking the check-mark next to 'Enable Wireless' in the network applet on the launcher bar (top of the screen). After re-enabling wifi by clicking on the same setting again, I can join the wifi network.